# Cannot reinitialise DataTable, jquery data table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jquery data table

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                   Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Firstname
                </th>
                <th>
                    Lastname
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

and js initialization code

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
        $('#dataTables-table').dataTable({        
            "bDestroy": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "/Home/ShowData"
        });
 });
```

On loading html page I'm getting

**DataTables warning: table id=dataTables-table - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.**

Comment: You have already done this somewhere else on your page - `$('#dataTables-table').dataTable({`. In that case, check if DT is already initialized and act accordingly.

Comment: what version number of datatables are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Based on ***most*** of the options you are passing to the dataTable constructor, it appears that you are using DataTables V1.10 or later.

If that is the case, then solving your issue could be as simple as changing this option:

```
"bDestroy": true
```

The 'bDestroy' option is part of [legacy code](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options) meant to work with DataTables V1.90 or earlier.

The [options for DataTables V1.10+](https://www.datatables.net/reference/option/) require that you use this format:

```
"destroy": true
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Online documentation](https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3) has a page specifically for this issue.

It looks like this indicates you may have somewhere else in your code that is trying to initialise the same datatable, but this is difficult to tell without your entire code file.

Answer (score 0):

> From the [doc](https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3): This error is triggered by passing in options to a DataTables constructor object when the DataTable instance for the selected node has already been initialised.

In such a case, you will want to use the `$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()` static method. This can be used to check if a table is a DataTable or not already

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $table;
    //Check if it's already initialized.
    if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#dataTables-table' ) ) {
        //Get an instace of the data table
        $table = $('#dataTables-table').dataTable();
        //CAUTION: the below line destroys the data table
        $table.destroy();
        //Create data table
        $('#dataTables-table').dataTable({        
            "bDestroy": true,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "/Home/ShowData"
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with destroying the previous declaration of data table as given below

```
$("#dataTables-table").DataTable().destroy();
```

And then add your data table creation code below it.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript put this code

```
   $('#idTable').dataTable({
destroy: true });
```